# Adding an individual to repeating events

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

I have set up an after school event every monday for six weeks. 
It's $5 for each session, but if they register for all sessions it's $20 rather than $30.

Currently I have to add the child to all six events individually. Is there some way to add a child to all events in a repetition? Also wondering whats the best way to handle this payment set up? I am unsure how to do it without charging $120 at the moment!

I tried having a look and the registration for multiple events was a requested feature in 2015. Is there any update on this? An extension that could help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Multiple Event Registration](https://civicrm.org/extensions/multiple-event-registration) extension can handle this.